# how to install react-boostrap using pnpm

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, vite, pnpm

The project I am working on currently uses pnpm as the package manager, I tried to install the react-boostrap library package in the project (pnpm i react-bootstrap) but this did not work. I also checked the node_module folder and there is a file of react-boostrap but it is not working.

i already search on internet but didn't get proper solution, so i tried this command `pnpm i react-boostrap` but didn't work.
remember i am using vite as front end tool.
pnpm 7.17.1
react 8.15.0
vite 8.15.0

Comment: What is "not working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to include css. You have to do it manually:

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets

Comment: oh ! actually i forgot about that. its work  thanks !